# How long since last time app was opened in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, time

How can I tell the time from the last time my app was open?  Can this still be monitored even my app is not running in the background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put something like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"kLastCloseDate"];
```

in both

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then check the difference at startup:

```
NSDate *lastDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kLastCloseDate"];
NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate];
// your stuff
```

in both

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

In your application delegates `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method, just write the current time to a file. Then, in either `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, read this file and compare with the current time. The difference will tell you how long since your application was last foremost.

Comment: Might I recommend NSUserDefaults specifically?